# Images dissapear in excel documents when copying them with python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

```
import openpyxl

def factuur():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('factuurvoorbeeld1.xlsx')
    Blad1 = wb.active
    Blad1['K7'] = 'logo.png'
    Blad1['E22'] = factuurNr.get()
    Blad1['E23'] = datum.get()
    Blad1['E24'] = debNr.get()
    Blad1['E25'] = locatie.get()
    wb.save('{}.xlsx'.format(factuurNr.get() + ',' + debNr.get()))
```

I'm trying to program an application that automatically fills in Excel documents by using a simple GUI and entry fields. The problem is, everytime python makes a copy of the base Excel file (The one with personal information that is in every document along with one image), the image dissappears. Do any of you guys know what to do about this? I'm using Python 3.5.

Things I have tried:
1) multiple Excel modules
2) Something about writing code in excel(Not sure if I did this correctly though)

Sorry for my horrible description, I'm don't really know how to describe this kind of stuff.
If you want to know more, just leave a question in the comments, I will check as often as i can.

Blad1 = The first sheet of the excel document.

Comment: We need to see the code doing the actual copy, at least...

Comment: I just installed Pillow by "pip install Pillow" and it worked like a charm. I believe openpyxl does not load the image inside Xl file while loading the xl file if Pillow lib is not installed. It does not complain either making an impression that openpyxl can not load the images while loading xl file. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately openpyxl does not support images at this time, see official documentation:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html

> openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file
>   so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are
>   opened and saved with the same name.

So when you open the template file, the images are not read, thus not saved in the new file.

It might work if you insert the image again with openpyxl, by following the doc here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#inserting-an-image

Comment: Thanks for the time! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I would guess this answer is deprecated :)

Answer (score 30):

I face same issue with [openpyxl 2.6.2](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/)

Logo images was added in template excel file but disappear in exported .xlsx file

I just install [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) and now its exporting all images fine.

```
pip install Pillow
```

This is my sample code to create salary slip from template excel file:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def create_salary_slip():
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'salary.xlsx')
    # grab the active worksheet
    ws = wb.active
    # Add Income
    ws['D11'] = 25000
    # Add deduction
    ws['M11'] = 1500
    # Save the file
    wb.save("sample.xlsx")

create_salary_slip()
```

Comment: This worked indeed! Must be an internally used library in openpyxl or something. I ran a virtual environment for my project, installed the library for that project and it worked.

Comment: thx a lot. `openpyxl` should definitely display a warning message when `Pillow` is missing and you are saving a workbook containing images

Comment: As of 2020, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: jezz, this is super frustrating. Thank a lot mate

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and tried a lot of libs.
For me [editpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/editpyxl/) does exactly what I need in that scenario:

```
import editpyxl

wb = editpyxl.Workbook()  
source_filename = r'Template.xlsx'
destination_filename = 'Output.xlsx'

wb.open(source_filename)
ws = wb.active
ws.cell('A1').value = 3.14
wb.save(destination_filename)
wb.close()
```