# Why does my header image disappear from my template?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I made a template document in Excel which is mostly empty, except for the header which contains the logo of our department (below).

[image: template doc]

I then read this template document into python using `openpyxl` and populate it with a data frame. However, when I save the workbook and open the Excel doc, everything is intact except my image disappears.

How can I ensure my logo stays intact in the report? I know I can't insert an image into the header in `openpyxl`, so I was hoping by including it in my template (and never touching the header) it would stay but it isn't.

**Code in Python**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = load_workbook('./template.xlsx')
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save("{}".format(fn))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images dissapear in excel documents when copying them with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606139/images-dissapear-in-excel-documents-when-copying-them-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately openpyxl does not support images at this time, see official documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook

> openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file
>   so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are
>   opened and saved with the same name.

So when you open the template file, the images are not read, thus not saved in the new file.
Therefore, you may have to switch to using xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: as openpyxl does not support graphics in header and xlsxwriter does not support modyfing existing data. I did modification wit openpyxl as normal and at the end added logo again with vba.

```vba
Sub Main()
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wb      As Workbook
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    strPath = "D:/your_path/"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)
    
        For iIndex = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(iIndex)
    
            'Add image.
            With ws.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture
               .Filename = "D:/your_logo.jpg"
               .Height = 60
               .Width = 80
            End With
            ' Add image to header
            ws.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&G"
    
        Next iIndex
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
        
     strFile = Dir 'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.
    Loop
End Sub
```