# openpyxl not displaying image while running on aws lambda (probably due to problem with Pillow?)

Tags: python, excel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using openpyxl to create an excel file.

Basically, I have an excel template with the logo of my company, I edit some part of it and when I save it using AWS LAMBDA, the logo is gone, it leaves blank cells as if the logo were never there.

It's working great on my local machine (windows 10 PRO) so this must be related to aws lambda but couldn't find what may explain this.

The package installed are the same, openpyxl==3.0.4 as of today

What could be the issue ?

As per the topic here [Images dissapear in excel documents when copying them with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606139/images-dissapear-in-excel-documents-when-copying-them-with-python), I've tried to add pillow in my packages but it didn't change anything...

edit: I've also tried to do like this:

```
   img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[0] / 'logo.png')
   wb['Data'].add_image(img, 'B1')
```

but it doesn't work either in Lambda, it's saying that Pillow isn't installed (whereas it's in my requirements.txt and all other packages are correctly installed)